# Why my form.py can't read field HEIGHT from models?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am trying to run my app, however I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'HEIGHT' is not defined
```

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

HEIGHT = [
    ('XS', 'Extra Small'),
    ('S', 'Small'),
    ('M', 'Medium'),
    ('L', 'Large'),
    ('XL', 'Extra Large')]class Dog(models.Model):

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=HEIGHT, null=False)

class DogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'weight', 'height']
```

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class DogForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = forms.IntegerField()
    weight= forms.IntegerField()
    height = forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.Select(choices=HEIGHT))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you declared **HEIGHT** in forms.py

Comment: what is this...??? `('XL', 'Extra Large')]class Dog(models.Model):` please correct the question if by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving Height choices to the model so you don't have to remember to import it every time you want to use it. Also you can use the Django's built in models.TextChoices.

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Dog(models.Model):
    class Height(models.TextChoices):
        XS = 'XS', 'Extra Small'
        S =  'S', 'Small'
        M = 'M', 'Medium'
        L = 'L', 'Large'
        XL = 'XL', 'Extra Large'
        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Height.choices, null=False)

class DogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'weight', 'height']
```

Now whenever you want to access Height outside of models.py you just `from [app].models import Dog` and then it's accessible under `Dog.Height`. Making use of `models.TextChoices` gives you option to access names, values and labels of each choice easier. For example:

```
Dog.Height.XL.value == 'XL' # True
Dog.Height.XL.label == 'Extra Large' # True
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import HEIGHT

class DogForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = forms.IntegerField()
    weight= forms.IntegerField()
    height = forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.Select(choices=HEIGHT))
```